# Why does using encodeURIComponent lock up my webpage when angle brackets are in the 'will-be' encoded values?

Tags: javascript, http, url, encoding

I'm starting to get to the point where I understand how and when to encode for purposes of both mitigating XSS and displaying characters correctly.

I have however some client-side script (JavaScript) that is writing some html to a page, specifically into a querystring.

For this I have used javascript's "encodeURIComponent" function to help assist with handling the user-input that is stored in an external json file.

I have noticed that no matter how I tried to encode these values, when angle brackets are in any of the values it actually locks up the page, every time, but works perfectly when no angle brackets are in the json values.

I have tried html encoding first, then using "encodeURIComponent" and also trying this the other way around. Since javascript doesn't have an inborn html encoder, I have written a simple one of my own. It is here:

```
function htmlEncode (input)
{

    while(input.indexOf("&") > -1)
    {
        input = input.replace("&", "&amp;")
    }
    while(input.indexOf("<") > -1)
    {
        input = input.replace("<", "&lt;")
    }
    while(input.indexOf(">") > - 1)
    {
        input = input.replace(">", "&gt;")
    }
    while(input.indexOf("\"") > -1)
    {
        input = input.replace("\"", "&#x22;")
    }
    while(input.indexOf("'") > -1)
    {
        input = input.replace("'", "&#x27;")
    }
    while(input.indexOf("/") > -1)
    {
        input = input.replace("/", "&#x2F;")
    }

    return input
}
```

And here is a javascript snippet of the code that writes the values to the page (without the html encoder):

```
stringCompiler = "/Event htms/Event.cshtml?title=" + encodeURIComponent(jsonObj.events[i].title) +
                        "&explanation=" + encodeURIComponent(jsonObj.events[i].explanation) + "&dateString=" +
                        encodeURIComponent(jsonObj.events[i].dateMonth) + "-" + encodeURIComponent(jsonObj.events[i].dateNumber) + "-" + encodeURIComponent(jsonObj.events[i].dateYear);
```

Unfortunately, I can't offer any more information than that, because, when it locks up, it locks up hard, and no diagnostic tools can be run (can't even right-click or scroll).

I thought encoding something twice was silly, but when the angle brackets locked up the browser with the use of "encodeURIComponent" alone, I figured I would try html encoding, too, but it still locks up either way.

Is there anything I can do, or should I just prevent angle brackets when saved to the json file?

-----------------------THIS IS WHAT I'M SEEING WITH BELOW FUNCTION-----------------

[image: Your Function]

Comment: can you show a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it locking up? I just did a couple tests, and worked fine for me on FF 18.

Comment: @Chad try with angle brackets in the string.

Comment: I have, a couple times: `var str = '<thing/>'; encodeURIComponent(str);` returns `"%3Cthing%2F%3E"` instantly. I'm also confused because the codes you are replacing some things with are not URL-encoded, they are HTML entity codes.

Comment: @Chad oh well there's no problem at all with `encodeURIComponent()`; I meant the function posted in the question.

Comment: @Pointy AH! That was unclear, thought `encodeURIComponent()` was breaking.

Comment: @Chad I think the OP thought it was, though I don't know why.

Comment: @Pointy Well, to be honest, it locks up when I use only the encodeURIComponent method and not even include my htmlEncode function (as long as angle brackets are in the values).

Comment: @VoidKing see this: http://jsfiddle.net/cJmy8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do **much** better than that.  I bring you my good friend, the letter "g":

```
function htmlEncode (input) {
  return input.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;')
    .replace(/'/g, '&#x27;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&#x22;');
}
```

Your code is having problems because of "&".  Your code says:

1. Are there any ampersands in this string?
2. If yes, then replace the first one with `&amp;`
3. Go to step 1.

See the problem?  You'll **always** have ampersands in the string.  By using `.replace()` with the "global" qualifier on the regular expression, you replace **all** of them in one call.

There's another way to do that, one that *might* be faster, involving just one call to `.replace()` and a function argument, but I think it's needlessly complicated.

The `encodeURIComponent()` does **not** "hang" on any input, as you can see yourself if you type

```
encodeURIComponent("<>&");
```

into your browser's console.

Comment: I see from your 3 step demonstration, exactly what you mean. This is the first time my self written htmlEncode function has locked up like this. I can see how using reg. expressions here would be better (although, as I'm sure you can tell, I am not that practiced at it, or I would have probably tried that first). I will try this, now, and be right back!

Comment: One quick question, though:  Is it stupid to encode twice or necessary to encode twice here? I think it is necessary, as it locks up without me using my htmlEncode function, at all, though.

Comment: @VoidKing well `encodeURIComponent` works fine for me; perhaps you could add the code that calls it in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry did you mean the whole function? It is kind of a large ajax call.

Comment: The line of your example (.replace(/\\/g, '&#x22;')) isn't correct, since &#x22; is the hex code for ". Did you mean the hex code for 'backslash'?

Comment: Also, I can't use your code for at least one syntax error.  Using " in the regular expression makes javascript think I mean a "string"

Comment: I'll check the syntax, @VoidKing

Comment: @VoidKing that syntax is fine - when I cut/paste it into the Firefox console it works; you're right that the entities are off so I'll fix those.

Comment: oh, ok, so the intellisense I am working with is falsely being tricked? (This function is in an external .js file)

Comment: Sry, again, but you wrote "&#22;". did you mean "&#x22"? If so, this is the hex code for double-quotes and not an apostrophe, where it is located. Also the same is true for the line underneath that.

Comment: @AD7six But it also includes multiple calls to "encodeURIComponent"

Comment: @VoidKing I promise that there's no way that `encodeURIComponent()` is causing your problem.  I don't think you're dreaming up the lock-up, but something else must be causing it.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, I agree, and if you want the whole ajax function, I'll give it to you, but there will be a lot (if not all) irrelevant parts, and is a pretty sizeable look-through.

Comment: @Pointy I used your example in a function and it breaks javascript. This doesn't surprise me since the syntax makes part of one line think it's a comment (because of the // in .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F;')) and parts of two other lines think they are strings.

Comment: @Pointy I think you have to use this syntax:  "$TESTONE $TESTONE".replace( new RegExp("\\$TESTONE","gm"),"foo")

Comment: @VoidKing no, you don't.  JavaScript supports a "native" regex syntax, and it's just as I've coded it in my sample code. The answer (after fixing it; that is, as it is now) works fine.

Comment: @Pointy Are we talking about JavaScript? I mean I know you know what you're talking about, but it kind of feels like I'm in the twilight zone right now because it makes perfect sense to me that it wouldn't be able to tell one set of '//' from another set of '//'

Comment: @Pointy And I swear, it breaks JavaScript

Comment: Wow, this is crazy! Thanks for trying to help but I almost feel like I am being given wrong answers on purpose, LOL This post should be deleted. Both the question and the answers are all rubbish (no offense intended) and completely not helpful.

Comment: @VoidKing I can copy that code to my Firefox console and it works. I'll make a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @VoidKing [here is a working jsfiddle that uses the function in my answer.  It does not "break JavaScript".](http://jsfiddle.net/dMen8/)

Comment: My friend, I coded the function exactly like you have it in an external .js file and it breaks. I remove function, it works. The intellisense is showing more colors in that function than most rainbows have.

Comment: @VoidKing have you looked at the fiddle?  Does it work in your browser? (What browser are you using anyway?)

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine. My only conclusion is (this is an assumption) that jsfiddle and js files are different or, that is, treated differently.

Comment: @VoidKing I assure you that that is not the case. The jsfiddle site simply presents that code to the browser, and the browser is 100% responsible for interpreting and running the code.

Comment: Okay, point taken. I have written thousands and thousands of Javascript functions, in-page and (mostly) in external files. I am not that familiar with Regular expressions, but I have read up on them in the past. That having been said, I assure you I know how to write a simple function and call it. Other than that, it is your code, exactly.

Comment: Well I don't know what to tell you, @VoidKing.  That regular expression syntax is fine, and works correctly in the jsfiddle.  I don't know exactly what errors you're getting; it may be better to frame it all in a separate question.

Comment: I have added an image to my post of what the code looks like in the js file in my editor.

Comment: @VoidKing well that looks like a bug with Intellisense and not with JavaScript.  The actual JavaScript interpreters have no problem with that syntax, because, well, it's correct.  In fact that's why it's necessary to put "\" before "/" in a regex literal: to tell the parser that the `/` is *part of* the regular expression and not the marker for the *end* of it.

Comment: perhaps, but it seems to be backed up by the fact that my JavaScript breaks when I use this function as is. (the break that appears that it doesn't run (or maybe it doesn't, like it thinks that there's a compiler error)).

Comment: @VoidKing if you don't see any errors reported in the JavaScript console, then there may be something else causing incorrect behavior.

Comment: Well, rather than be a coward and try to save face, I will say (with tail between legs) that I found another one of my "htmlEncode" functions (which obviously breaks things by checking for "&" then replacing "&amp;" and eternally checking over and over again). I had forgotten that this function communicates with this page, from another external js file. That having been said, I don't know what's wrong with my parser or why the page only errored when I put in angle brackets, but either way, on par with the original question, this answer has been accepted.

Comment: @VoidKing Well I'm glad you got your project back on track!!

Comment: I don't know how I'm gonna get to use regular expressions in a way that won't freak out my intellisense, though (I don't want to store it in a string, because I just know that will lead to double-escaping [or worse...] certain characters with special regex meanings. Perhaps new RegEx can help me here, since I just noticed it isn't suppposed to be wrapped in quotes (thus not a true string in JavaScript)

Comment: And I'm glad you had enough patience to help me :)

Comment: One last edit:  while trying to replace the apostrophe `(/'/g, &#x2C;)` You have coded to replace apostrophes with commas. The hex code you are looking for is `&#x27;`, I believe.

Comment: @VoidKing yes you're right; I just did `man ascii` in a terminal window and the output is a little confusing :-)

Comment: No prob, just thought you'd like to know :) Thanks again!

Comment: Also, for any it may help, I found a workaround to JavaScript's bad Intellisense [yes, I know, it's not really JavaScript's] here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251311/can-i-retain-sanity-to-webmatrixs-intellisense-when-using-regular-expressions-i