# Can I retain sanity to WebMatrix's Intellisense when using regular expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, webmatrix

I'm not sure why Microsoft hasn't allowed an Intellisense-friendly environment for using native regex with JavaScript in WebMatrix, but here is what I see when I attempt an otherwise normal JavaScript function:

[image]

As you can see, while this is perfectly valid JavaScript (using native regex), WebMatrix's Intellisense for my .js file is showing more random colors than a kaleidoscope.

I probably shouldn't be complaining, since it works, but I would like to restore human-readability if I can. I have noticed that this hasn't been mentioned anywhere else before (that I can find), and I was wondering if there were a more aesthetically pleasing way to handle this, given the environment.

I've tried using something like `new RegEx(/&/g)` for the first argument in the replace function, but of course, it produces the same glitch.

I've also tried storing the regex in a string, but I don't think that is in the format the first argument expects, so no dice there either.

I am not a master at regular expressions, by any means, so I apologize if I am overlooking a simple workaround here.

Is there anything I can do to retain this function in a more human-readable way?

--------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

I just noticed that the line `input = input.replace(/'/g, "&#x2C")` is actually replacing an apostrophe with a comma. Rather than reload the picture, I will just mention that here (the proper hex code for apostrophe should be `&#x27`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new RegExp(/&/g)` does not really make sense as the `/&/g` already creates a `RegExp` object. You can use `new RegExp('&', 'g')` instead.

By the way, this is not the only problem there is with JavaScript Intellisense.

Comment: I assume by, "JavaScript Intellisense" that you mean within WebMatrix, right? Just want to make sure we are talking about the same environment. Yeah, I'm not that superb with Regex nor its implementation in the JavaScript environment. Well, thanks for your answer, and I will give it a shot and be right back!

Comment: Well yes, I don't use WebMatrix professionally but Visual Studio instead. But it more or less works the same way, AFAIK.